# MySQL foreign key select matches

Tags: mysql

I have a database with articles. All articles have keywords. The keywords are in a separate table and keywords and articles are connected with a relational table, thusly:

**articles**

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `articleTitle` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `articleBody` text NOT NULL,
  `articlePermalink` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `articleAuthor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updatedAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**keywords**

```
CREATE TABLE `keywords` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `keyword` varchar(64) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**articlekeywords**

```
CREATE TABLE `articlekeywords` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `articleId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `keywordId` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I want to select all articles that have some or all keywords in common with any given article using articles.id as the identifier. Preferably with a single SQL call.

**EDIT:**

I ended up doing something very similar to what [Gordon Linoff suggested below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41323806/1986451).

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.articleTitle, a.articlePermalink
FROM articles a
JOIN articlekeywords ak ON a.id = ak.articleId
JOIN articlekeywords ak2 ON ak.keywordId = ak2.keywordId AND ak2.articleId = $articleId AND not(a.id = $articleId)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a self join.  You can get matching articles ordered by the number of keywords in common by doing:

```
select ak2.article2, count(*) as numKeywordsInCommon
from articlekeywords ak join
     articlekeywords ak2
     on ak.keywordid = ak2.keywordid and ak2.articleid = $arcticleid
group by ak2.articleid
order by numKeywordsInCommon desc;
```

Comment: I think there needs to be an inequality for id in the join to avoid joining the row with itself as OP asked for matching keywords.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure this does what I need. It tells me how many keywords match, but not which articles they match with. Use example: article #1 has a keyword, which article #2 also has. I need it to show article #1 and #2, when I search for matches on article #n. Like I wrote in OP, I need to select the articles, not the matching keywords.

Comment: I am going to accept this answer, because I ended up doing something very similar, which I will update in my original question. Thank you, @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a full listing identified by the relationships in the articlekeywords table:

```
SELECT * FROM articlekeywords AKW
JOIN articles A ON AKW.articleId = A.Id
JOIN keywords K ON AKW.keywordId = K.Id
-- WHERE (some condition you'd like to do for further filtering)
```

Comment: After re-reading the question I see you may be wanting to do something closer to what @GordonLinoff recommended if you're trying to identify only articles that have keywords in common.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that same thing, but thank you anyway :)